# SQL extract multiple numeric values from string column

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, numeric

I read and used the function suggested in this article:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/14/sql-server-get-numeric-value-from-alpha-numeric-string-udf-for-get-numeric-numbers-only/

and it works nice but actually I need the result in two columns (I'm expecting two numbers that should be seperated with spaces and / char in the original string)

Let's say "nfsdklj6 / 3 ddfsdf" should be 6 | 3
"nfsdklj45 / 100 ddfsdf" should be 45 | 100

I'm a rookie sql programmer, so any help or hint would be appreciated,
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the mentioned udf

```
Declare @Table table (MyString varchar(25))
Insert into @Table (MyString) values 
('nfsdklj6 / 3 ddfsdf'),
('nfsdklj45 / 100 ddfsdf')

Select * 
      ,Val1=dbo.udf_GetNumeric(substring(MyString,1,charindex('/',MyString)))
      ,Val2=dbo.udf_GetNumeric(substring(MyString,charindex('/',MyString),50))
 From @Table
```

Returns

```
MyString                Val1    Val2
nfsdklj6 / 3 ddfsdf     6       3
nfsdklj45 / 100 ddfsdf  45      100
```

For your specific table

```
Select Shuma 
      ,Val1=dbo.udf_GetNumeric(substring(Shuma,1,charindex('/',Shuma)))
      ,Val2=dbo.udf_GetNumeric(substring(Shuma,charindex('/',Shuma),50))
 From [dbo],[Deals] 
 Where Shuma not like LIKE '%1 / 1%'
```

Comment: thanks!! my values should come from other select query of that column that hold the original strings... what is the correct syntax for that?

Comment: that's the query that should return the values: SELECT Shuma
 FROM [dbo].[Deals]
 WHERE Shuma NOT LIKE '%1 / 1%'

Comment: Updated my answer for your structure

Comment: great, thanks John!  I barely writing sql queries, you saved my day (: